# onClick array.push overwriting previous elements React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to add multiple values to my `key: []` onclick, but it keeps overwriting my previous entry

```
  const handleClick = e => {
    console.log('click ', e)
    let choice = {
      key: e.keyPath[1],
      value: [],
    }
    choice.value.push(e.keyPath[0])

    console.log('choice', choice)
    let newFilterChoice = {
      ...filterChoice,
      [choice.key]: choice.value,
    }

    updateFilter(newFilterChoice)
    console.log('filter', filterChoice)
  }
```

first click output looks like this `{role: ['value 1']}`,
second click `{role: ['new value']}`

expected output should be `{role: ['value 1', 'new value']}`

Comment: `newFilterChoice[[choice.key]].push(choice.value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the key with the new value, not appending it.

```
let newFilterChoice = {
  ...filterChoice,
  [choice.key]: choice.value, // <-- this replaces what used to be there
}
```

I think you intended to keep previously set values for the key so you should probably do this:

```
const oldChoice = filterChoice[e.keyPath[1]];
let choice = {
  key: e.keyPath[1],
  value: oldChoice ? oldChoice.value : []  // <-- keep existing values
}
choice.value.push(e.keyPath[0])
let newFilterChoice = {
  ...filterChoice,
  [choice.key]: choice.value, 
}
```

Or you could avoid creating a new object unless necessary like this:

```
const oldChoice = filterChoice[e.keyPath[1]];
let choice = oldChoice ? oldChoice : {
  key: e.keyPath[1],
  value: [] 
}
choice.value.push(e.keyPath[0])
let newFilterChoice = {
  ...filterChoice,
  [choice.key]: choice.value, 
}
```

Comment: I prefer this solution over the others as I don't need to introduce a new state variable to append new values, however I am getting an error on line `choice.value.push(e.keyPath[0])` `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
`

Comment: That should only happen if there is no value array. Is it possible that there is an object with the key but no value?

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you are creating a new local `choice` variable each time that function is called, so `choice.values` will always start as `[]`.

What you probably want to do there is to move that `choice` variable to state and update that each time you handle a click. Something like this:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [choiceValues, setChoiceValues] = React.useState([]);
  
  const handleClick = React.useCallback((e) => {
    const { value } = e.target.dataset;
    
    setChoiceValues(prevChoiceValues => {
      // Append the new value to the old ones creating a new array (no `prevChoiceValues.push`,
      // otherwise the reference won't change and React won't be able to track your change:
      const nextChoiceValues = [...prevChoiceValues, value];
      
      // Do something else with `nextChoiceValues` here:
      // updateFilter(nextChoiceValues);
      
      // Return them to update the state:
      return nextChoiceValues;
    });
  }, []);
  
  const nextValue = choiceValues.length;
  
  return (<React.Fragment>
    <button onClick={ handleClick } data-value={ nextValue }>Add value { nextValue }</button>
    
    <pre>{ choiceValues.join(', ') }</pre>
  </React.Fragment>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
body,
button {
  font-family: monospace;
}

body, p {
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

button {
  margin: 32px 0;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming a few things, when the click handler `handleClick` is triggered, the `choice`, the `newFilterChoice`, etc., are all redefined. You might need to use something like `this.state` or `useState` hook to have your sessions stored.

Also, when you try to create your `newFilterChoice`, the `choice` is actually recreated and added.

You may want to change the logic here:

```js
let choice = {
  key: e.keyPath[1],
  value: [],
}
```

The `value` above should refer to the stored choices somewhere. A better example here would be:

```js
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    choices: []
  };
  handleClick = () => {
    const choices = [...this.state.choices];
    choices.push(new Date());
    this.setState({ choices });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.choices, null, 2)}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, domContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```